# How to manage spark subscription?

Tags: civicrm-spark

We have since 1 year a subscription to Spark, but I don't remember where I can administer the subscription... I would like to check the payments situation of our spark account, etc... 
With my "admin" user account, I can work on our database, but I don't find how to manage the account/subscription. Thx a lot for your help and sorry for the trivial question...

Marc Aellen

Our database: https://focolarisuisseromande.civicrm.org/

Comment: There is a spark channel at https://chat.civicrm.org for support for spark - I would ask in there instead.

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM Spark sends a monthly billing email that includes a cancellation link.

It is also possible to login to https://civicrm.org/user (or create a new account) to view your past invoices.

If you have any other questions, feel free to contact us at spark@civicrm.org.